# Interface / Logic design technique in c

Tags: c, interface, logic

I have an interface which will allow external subsystems to use my system.

Do C programs usually use interfaces?

I have a core logic module which I want to use to handle the core of the system, this would mean that the interface would send the data to the core and the core will pass the data along possibly returning data too.

Is this a good way of doing things? It feels like there is an extra layer of data passing which is possibly not needed. On the other hand, I wouldnt want the interface to be directly connected to the lower system.

Is this extra layer of data handling a good thing or is it redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do C programs usually use interfaces?

- Header files represent an interface

Is this a good way of doing things?

- IMHO yes. In object orientation it is called [Facade Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) and hides the complexity of the underlying components. And provides a simpler API to the client.

Is this extra layer of data handling a good thing or is it redundant?

- If things aren't trivial it is worth the effort to implement the extra layer.

Comment: Well, it feels like a redundancy because the same functions will be used, BUT, I dont want to have a bunch of code in the interface file. e.g some logic code etc.

Comment: @Helium3 - You should, as a rule, have definitions in the `.h`-file, not logic.

Comment: @gnud: I think my working is being confused. Interface file meaning e.g. interface.c not logic.h. But I think I am making unneeded code when thinking of an interface.c. the logic.h could just as well be the interface to the inner system from an external sub system?

Comment: Declare your functions in the `mystash.h` file. Implement them in the `mystash.c` file. Include the `mystash.h` file wherever you use the functions, and link against the `mystash.o` object. No redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

It may make sense to copy data from external subsystems to your system. One situation I can think of is when the data is transient so must be copied while it is still available. It really depends on how your module will be used.

Once the data is in your system though, it doesn't make sense to copy it further. I wouldn't copy it from your "interface module" to your "core logic module", for example. Copying data will just slow the program down without any benefit.

Comment: I didnt mean copy though. I was thinking more in regards to having functions in the interface which are almost identical to those in the core logic, just for the sake of having an extra layer of abstraction. But the actual data wouldnt be passed, I would be passing around pointers. Is this inteface even needed, or will the logic become the interface?